# frame rate doubles on Keypress HTML Canvas JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

For some reason my frame rate seems to double when changing the image through a keypress. the animation works fine but they game becomes unplayable when the character has been moved so many times.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a single `<img>` element, for which you change the `src` on keydown.

Every time the image has loaded, its `load` event fires, and since in this load event you do start a new `animate` loop, your logic goes twice has fast at each keydown, before the computer starts to loose power because of the so many loops being stacked, running all in the same frame.

An easy solution to avoid it would be to store multiple images, that you'd load only once, at initialisation.

Then, you would just have to keep track of which of these image is the one to be drawn in a variable, and update only this variable to point to one of the other images in the keydown event.

Comment: i thought this might be the problem.... i have tried creating a variable would i have to create multiple "myImages" and then a new variable which holds which one is selected in where it loads the image in the array? thanks

Comment: @Binnerz92, well you've got several ways of implementing it, either one Array or one Object which holds all your images to be loaded,, and one variable which you update to be the index/key to the image you want to draw, either (less clean IMO) 4 different variables for all your images, and one variable for the current one.

Comment: Found a easy fix i just created a bigger sprite sheet and changed the original image so that It just loaded a single image and upon key press the y valye within the drawImage chnages.

Comment: @Binnerz92, yep that's a good implementation too, a bit harder to maintain, and maybe not what I would recommend for developement, but it's good for prod. Here is [an rough example](https://jsfiddle.net/1dkh2ndy/) of what I was talking about